# get a value from a radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a radio button in my .aspx page and in the code behind I have written the following:

```
if (rbOnlyCreatedorUpdated.Checked == true)
{
    searchObject.CreatedOrUpdatedOnValidDate = SearchCritera.OnlyCreatedOrUpdated;
}
else if (rbOnlyOld.checked == true)
{
    searchObject.CreatedOrUpdatedOnValidDate = SearchCritera.OnlyOld;
}
else
{
    searchObject.CreatedOrUpdatedOnValidDate = SearchCritera.AllChanged;
}
```

And I really dislike the above. It feels clumsy and unclean. I would like a value to be returned by the radio button itself (named rbOnlyCreatedOrUpdatedOnValidDate, i.e the GroupName).

Is it possible or is the above the correct way to get the value?

Comment: from the above code it appears that you have TWO radio button lists ?

Comment: Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Checked` property of `RadioButton` will return either `true` or `false`. So no need to compare with `boolean` values (`true` or `false`).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `RadioButtonList` control, you can access the selected radiobuttons value by using `IdOfRadioButtonList.SelectedValue`. 
This will give you a string, so you will still have to do the conversion to one of the SearchCriteria class' properties yourself...

If it makes you feel any better, you can make it into a ternary operator, like so:

```
searchObject.CreatedOrUpdatedOnValidDate = 
    rbOnlyCreatedorUpdated.Checked ? SearchCritera.OnlyCreatedOrUpdated : 
    rbOnlyOld.checked ? SearchCritera.OnlyOld : 
    SearchCritera.AllChanged;
```